# How do I fix index out of range error message in C#?

Tags: c#

Getting an index out of range error message on line 49 "if (myNumber == myPartyAges[i])" I can't figure out why. using Visual studio basic set up here is the code:

```
List<int> myPartyAges = new List<int>() { 24, 44, 54, 39, 17, 24, 21 };

int myNumber = myPartyAges[5];
bool contains = false;

for (int i = myPartyAges[5] - 1; i >= 1; i--)
{
    if (myNumber == myPartyAges[i])
    {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (contains == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number found.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number not found.");
}
```

Comment: use a debugger it will help you understand. Tip watch the value of i on each increment

Comment: `i` starts out as 23. There are only 7 values in `myPartyAges`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. Could you please explain that. I saw that in Vis studio but I didn't know what it meant.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to do

```
for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
```

instead of

```
for (int i = myPartyAges[5] - 1; i >= 1; i--)
```

?

Comment: I don't want to search the whole length. I want to start at a specific index.

Comment: Ok you can do this, but not at index 23 like in the code you posted... I changed my code accordingly.